# How to prevent vibration of calls from one contact?

Tags: contacts, calls, vibration, 8.1-oreo

I have a contact who calls me regularly on Wednesday evenings. 
I already set her ring tone to "nothing", but cannot find any method to prevent the vibration.

Using regularly silent-mode, but I cannot keep on when working so it is not an option.

Wanted result: mute and turn-off for calls of one contact

Phones: OnePlus 3T and Samsung Galaxy S8
OS: Oreo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it without third party apps. You can try apps like "Good Vibration"